# How to cache remote images in a NodeJS / AngularJS app?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, caching

The scenario:

- A user posts a link to a website
- A little AngularJS service fetches a preview, including an image
- This information (including the remote URL of the image) is copied to a hidden form and sent to the server when the user clicks submit.
- Now I have to download the image to my server for the preview. Otherwise I would be hotlinking them which isn't good and could also cause problems later.

Because of the cross-origin policy I guess this can only be done server side.

My idea so far is to create a little API where I pass in the URL to the image and the server checks if a local copy exists and if not downloads one on the fly

```
http://example.com/staticapi/v1/get?img_url=ENCODED-IMG-URL
```

What I don't like about this idea is that a malicious user could just bombard this system with URLs.

An alternative would be to save the remote URL temporarily and let a background job download any remote images that haven't been processed yet.

How would you approach this?

Comment: I guess, you need to consider the post request as a means to post the image data. A get API is not a harm, but post is great. And that said, the logic to check for attacks varies with implementation. One way, Continuous IP requests need to be monitored and asked with security measures like CAPTCHA or something.

Comment: I disagree. A GET API could be harm if every call makes the server download an external resource. That is like an invitation for a DDOS attack. And since it will be called from the client via Javascript I cannot limit access to certain IPs. CAPTCHA might be an option, the API would have to monitor access and return a status that makes the frontend ask for a captcha. But that seems overcomplicated. Maybe using a background job is the easiest way.

Comment: Agreed, I mentioned a GET ApI being harmful in context of server downloading the image for you. So is that not bad? Anyways correct me if I'm wrong. The other thing you can consider is, session request's which would tell how many times a specific session has requested the resource to be saved, with count and last request time.